# Getting noise texture to flow continuously across multiple objects

Tags: texturing

I have 3 separate planes that are contiguous and have a common material.  I have applied a noise texture which I later want to use for displacement.  However, the noise texture shows up on the seams, it has clearly been stamped on each of the objects from the same origin point, as can be seen in the first image.

[image: Noise texture clearly shows seams]

Is it possible to make this seamless?  For example, if I do the same thing with the wave texture, it goes across the objects seamlessly, as below.

[image: Wave texture has no seams]

Thanks

Comment: What kind of texture coordinates are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of doing it is to add an empty to the scene and using it as a texture coordinates provider in the material. My guess is that you have something like this for now:

[image]

So after adding an empty to the scene and using it in the texture coordinates node, you'll get this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I was trying to do.  Thank heaps!